# $.Post doesn't work in Intel XDK

Tags: php, jquery, intel-xdk

I've a basic code in xdk.
An app with one button and the code for that button is :

```
$.post("http://url/test.php", {test:'1'}, 
            function(res){
                alert(res);
            }
       );
```

For testing purpose, I've a php code in a godaddy server.

The php code is :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['test'])){
   if ($_POST['test'] = '1')
       echo "AOK";
   else
      echo "NOK1";
}
else
    echo "NOK2";
```

When I run this as 'emulate' in XDK and press the button, I am getting

> NOK2

as my output.

What is going wrong or what am I missing ?

*Update*

The same code how-ever works for GET, and the output is

> AOK

Php Code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['test'])){
   // echo var_dump($_GET) ;
   if ($_GET['test'] = '1')
       echo "AOK";
   else
      echo "NOK1";
}
else{
    //echo var_dump($_POST) ;
    echo "NOK2";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'http://url/test.php',
          data:{test:'1'},
          success: function(res){alert(res);},
          error:function(res){alert(res);},
          dataType: 'text'
        });
```

Replacing GET with POST causes the problem.

Comment: Considering what I am posting, I should be getting 'AOK' I believe!

Comment: output of var_dump() : array(0){ }

Comment: doesn't work! @madalin

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code fix this and check if it work. I just verified that POST request work with intel XDK.
In the following line you have a mistake.

```
if ($_POST['test'] = '1')
```

in case you could not figure it out here is what it is supposed to be.

```
if ($_POST['test'] == '1')
```