# Cordova Hybrid App fails, Legacy Android Build Works

Tags: android, ios, cordova, intel-xdk

I've written a small application to test the working of cordova app on XDK.
The source code is same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252973/post-doesnt-work-in-intel-xdk)

However, I am attaching the code here :

```
(function()
{
 "use strict";
 /*
   hook up event handlers 
 */
 function register_event_handlers()
 {


     /* button  Login */
    $(document).on("click", ".uib_w_9", function(evt)
    {
        //intel.xdk.notification.showBusyIndicator(); 
       /*$.post("http://url/test.php", {test:'1'}, 
            function(res){
                alert(res);
            }
       );*/
        $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(){
            intel.xdk.notification.showBusyIndicator();
          },
          type: "GET",
          url: 'http://url/test.php',
          data:{test:'1'},
          success: function(res){
              alert(res);
              intel.xdk.notification.hideBusyIndicator(); 
          },
          error:function(res){
              alert(res);
              intel.xdk.notification.hideBusyIndicator(); 
          },
          dataType: 'text'
        });

    });

    }
 document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
})();
```

This is the JS file of the application.

The screenshot of the app in XDK emulator :

[image: The App Screen]

[image: The Working Screen]

Now When I do a build of the app using XDK cloud, I get a .apk file.

On uploading the file to GenyMotion Emulator, screen below :

[image: App Running in GenyMotion Emulator]

The click doesn't do anything, nor does the `showBusyIndicator()` show, nor the alert appear.

What am I missing and what is going wrong ?
I've plans to use this ide for a proper project and hence the testing, some help will be appreciated.

*UPDATE*

[image: The XDK Build page]
I did a Cordova Hybrid App build initially and that caused the problem.

When I did a legacy android build, then the problem was solved.

So what do I need to do to get it to work with the Cordova Build ?

Build Page :

[image: Build Page]

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with AJAX when Intel XDK builds apk with Cordova CLI version `4.1.2`. on Android version > `4.4`

There is a workaround, go to `Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Android`, change Cordova CLI version from `4.1.2` to `3.5` and AJAX should work.

Comment: I've already done that to no avail. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: in build settings, do u have domain list as `*`

Comment: Yes I have that. I've added a screenshot for your reference. @krisrak

Comment: I've sent you the zip

Comment: i emailed u the apk, u did not have `*`, i added that and it works on android device

Comment: I initially had *, I changed it to my domain which I wanted to whitelist. It work'd after that. When I've *, it isn't working!